# undoing /bin/dd, /sbin/mkswap, /sbin/swapon commands

Tags: linux

I use a VM box and I shot myself in the foot after attempting to fix a composer install that was failing without proper swaps, using of course someone else solution without knowing exactly what it did.

The instructions were as follows:

```
sudo /bin/dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/swap.1 bs=1M count=1024
/var/www$ sudo /sbin/mkswap /var/swap.1
sudo /sbin/swapon /var/swap.1
```

Now there is space issues and I'm not really sure how to reverse the above commands.  How can I reverse the commands made above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you did:

1. you created a 1 GiB file with `dd`;
2. set a swap area on the file with `mkswap`;
3. enabled the file for paging and swapping with `swapon`.

I assume each command was successful. To revert:

1. if the file is listed in the output of sole `swapon`, disable the file for paging and swapping:

   ```
   sudo swapoff /var/swap.1
   ```

   (if it's not listed, this means either your `swapon /var/swap.1` failed or the file has been disabled anyway (e.g. by rebooting); in such case proceed to the next step);
2. `mkswap` doesn't need to be reverted, proceed;
3. remove the file:

   ```
   sudo rm /var/swap.1
   ```

Note in general [`rm` will not free up space if the file is still in use](https://askubuntu.com/q/205915/693277). However after `swapoff` the file shouldn't be in use and there is no reason for any random process to use it, so most likely you will have no problem with this. I'm mentioning the possibility just in case.

Comment: I'm having an issue when running swapoff:
sudo /sbin/swapoff /var/swap.1
swapoff: /var/swap.1: swapoff failed: Invalid argument

visual check on folder reveals swap.1 is in the directory.

Comment: @alrightgame So maybe your `swapon` was not successful? Or have you rebooted since? What is the output of sole `swapon`? Is the file listed in the output?